# Best practice for executing code on mouseover (or mouseout) only

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, mouseout

I want to execute code when hovering an element. When pointer goes away I want nothing to happen. This code does exactly what I want:

```
$('li').hover(function() {
  // actions here
},
function() {
});

$('ul').hover(function() {
},
function() {
  // other actions here
});
```

But it's ugly. I was expecting this cleaner version to work:

```
$('li').mouseover(function() {
  // actions here
});

$('ul').mouseout(function() {
  // other actions here
});
```

But it doesn't. The `mouseover` part keeps firing as I move my pointer over the element, rather than firing once.

Any suggestion?

Comment: use a flag  and set it to false after it fires the first time.

Comment: When hovering any li element, I display a background image (associated with each li element). When hovering away from the entire list, I want to switch back to a default background image. When hovering between the li element, I DON'T want to switch to default image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an active class to `li` you enter....remove all active classes when leaving `ul`

```
$('li').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('ul').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).find('.active').removeClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ mouseenter instead of mouseover

Answer (score 0):

You're likely wanting to make use of [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Something like this should work:

`$('ul').on('mouseover', 'li', function() {
  console.log('hovered');
});`

Answer (score 0):

> The mouseover part keeps firing as I move my pointer over the element,
>   rather than firing once.

you could use a flag to only execute a block of code once, however, this doesn't stop the event from re-firing multiple times, it merely ignores the event after the first one.

```
var flag = true;
$('li').mouseover(function() {
   if(flag){

   // actions here
    flag = false;
   }
});
```

though, I would recommend looking into [**`.mouseenter()`**](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/).

**Snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
      var flag = true;
      $('li').mouseover(function() {
        if(flag){
          console.log("testing");
          // actions here
          flag = false;
        }
     });

    $('ul').mouseout(function() {
     // other actions here
    });

   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```